# Return an image from a Delphi REST server and show it in a browser

Tags: delphi, datasnap

When you return an image using a file stream object in a Delphi rest server, it will not display in a browser. Here is an example method that returns an image:

```
function TServerClass.Image: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := TFileStream.Create('pathtofile\image.png', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
end;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that Delphi REST server always sets the content type to text/html. This confuses the browser when you send other types of content. It is a bug, since most responses are json, which means the most sensible default content type should be application/json.

Fortunately there is a way to override the content type from within the server method.

You need to add Data.DBXPlatform to the uses list of your implementation.

This unit contains the function [GetInvocationMetadata](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DBXPlatform.GetInvocationMetadata), which gives access to the response that is being build. It returns a [TDSInvocationMetadata](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DBXPlatform.TDSInvocationMetadata) object which among varius other useful properties has the [ResponseContentType](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DBXPlatform.TDSInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType) property.

Setting this property overrides the Content-Type header that the method returns in the http response.

The given example becomes:

```
function TServerClass.Image: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := TFileStream.Create('pathtofile\image.png', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
  GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := 'image/png';
end;
```

Now the result image will be displayed properly in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this problem too trying to download different file types (png, pdf, xlsx, docx, etc...) from DataSnap REST server (Delphi XE3) to a JavaScript web client.
Some browsers (es.: FireFox) will take correct action anyway, but not all. Internet Explorer doesn't recognize the proper action for the downloaded file without correct content-type.
The @Anders solution initially seems to work for me because I was working with PDF and Firefox.
But when I've tested on IE (and others) and with different extensions, the files where not recognised. Using FireBug I've seen that Content-Type was always "text/html" and not the assigned one using

```
GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := '...my assigned content type ...';
```

The workaround found working for me is:

In ServerMethodsUnit

```
var
   ContentTypeHeaderToUse: string;  // Global variable

TServerMethods1.GetFile(params: JSON):TStream;
begin
   .... processing ....
   ContentTypeHeaderToUse := '...' (assign correct content type).
end;
```

In WebModuleUnit

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if ContentTypeHeaderToUse<>'' then begin
    Response.ContentType := ContentTypeHeaderToUse;
    ContentTypeHeaderToUse := ''; // Reset global variable
  end;
end;
```

I used a similar solution for assigning Content-Disposition too. This is a useful header key in order to set file name to download and attachment/inline mode.
With this one the code is:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if ContentDispositionHeaderToUse<>'' then begin
    Response.SetCustomHeader('content-disposition',ContentDispositionHeaderToUse);
    ContentDispositionHeaderToUse := '';
  end;
  if ContentTypeHeaderToUse<>'' then begin
    Response.ContentType := ContentTypeHeaderToUse;
    ContentTypeHeaderToUse := '';
  end;
end;
```

Assign ContentDispositionHeaderToUse into the server methods implementation.

**EDIT**

This workaround doesn't work in ISAPI DLL on IIS with data compression enabled!
With no data compressione (local debuggin IIS) the response header is:

```
Connection  close
Content-Disposition inline; filename="Privacy-0.rtf.pdf"
Content-Length  150205
Content-Type    application/pdf; charset=ISO-8859-1
Pragma  dssession=28177.371935.39223,dssessionexpires=1200000
```

but with production enabled IIS the response comes with:

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  11663
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Thu, 11 Sep 2014 21:56:43 GMT
Pragma  dssession=682384.52215.879906,dssessionexpires=1200000
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

Content-disposition and content-type assigned in DataSnap code are not surfaced.